# Lua - Set default value for multiple variables

Tags: lua, default-value

Is it possible to set default values for multiple variables in Lua? I seem to be having a hard time accomplishing this.

My logic:
1) It is possible to set values for multiple variables like this:

```
> one, two = "uno", "dos"
> print(one)
uno
> print(two)
dos
```

2) It is possible to set default values for variables like this:

```
> foo = string.match("/dir/example.txt", "dir/(..)/.*") or "ab"
> return print(foo)
ab
```

3) When I attempt to set default values for multiple variables, I run into a problem:

```
> foo, bar = string.match("/dir/xx/xx/example.txt", "/dir/(..)/(..)/.*") 
> print(foo)
xx
> print(bar)
zz

> foo, bar = string.match("/dir/xx/xx/example.txt", "/dir/(..)/(..)/.*") or "ab","cd"
> print(foo)
xx
> print(bar)
cd
```

What I suspect is happening is that it's treating everything before the final comma as the value of 'foo', and everything after it as the value of 'bar'.

Using this example, is it possible to indicate that these are expected to be default values if string.match does not provide a value?

Comment: FWIW, I tried a bunch of different ways to encapsulate "ab" and "cd" to get them to be understood as default values together, and scoured the forums but couldn't find a similar question, let alone an answer, before I decided to try posting here. :)

Comment: `if not foo then foo, bar = "ab", "cd" end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's explain what happening in cases 1 and 2, before tackling the problem you are facing

1. You are setting multiple values to multiple values. This is syntactic sugar provided by Lua, each variable is separated by a comma, likewise with each value
2. You are setting "default" values. You aren't really providing a default value here, just using a logical operation that performs a task with identical output. When you use the `or` command you pass 2 operands, the value you want to set, and the default if the first doesn my exist. The **only** reason this works is `or` returns the 2nd argument if the first is nil or false.

Now that we have the explanations out of the way, let's get into the problem itself.

```
a, b = str:match(pattern) or "y", "z"
```

Lua isn't reading that like you think it is. Lua sees that comma and essentially thinks

```
a = str:match(pattern) or "y"
b = "z"
```

Because that's what we said. We separated the values like explained in #1 Lua doesn't recognize you want to assign what match returns OR those 2 values.

As for fixing it... Well you have 2 options. You can just assign it regularly:

```
a,b = str:match(pattern)
if not (a and b) then
    a,b = "y","z"
end
```

Or you can use tables

```
t = {str:match(pattern)}
a,b = t[1] or "y", t[2] or "z"
```

It's entirely up to you

*My apologies if I misunderstood your question, please notify me in the comments if I have done so*

Comment: Thank you for the eloquent clarification and multiple solutions. :)

Comment: No problem, thank you for your contribution to SO ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet in cases like this is to just do something like:

```
foo, bar = someoperation()
foo = foo or defaultfoo
bar = bar or defaultbar
print(foo)
print(bar)
```

Comment: Yeah, setting the variable's default values individually works fine, I'm just surprised that you can't do so for multiple variables at once.