# Lua how can I assign multiple variables at once conditionally?

Tags: lua

Why does this work

```lua
local a, b =
  true
  and 1, 2
   or 3, 4

print(a, b) --> 1  2
```

but this doesn't?

```lua
local a, b =
  false
  and 1, 2
   or 3, 4

print(a, b) --> false  2
```

how can I make it work?

Comment: one option: https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/UUchScFWIS0xpzhVITEvRcFUIb9IwVBHoaSoFCJgBhIw@l9QlJlXogFSrvkfAA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lua - Set default value for multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870184/lua-set-default-value-for-multiple-variables)

Comment: You're assinging `local a = true and 1` and `local b = 2 or 3`. The `4` in both cases will be discarded.

Comment: And both statements work, I guess the problem here is what you're expecting them to do. Why do you say the second one doesn't work? What did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to think these work something like this (not actually valid syntax):

```
local a, b = true and (1, 2) or (3, 4)
local a, b = false and (1, 2) or (3, 4)
```

But that's not how they work. They really work as if you wrote this:

```
local a, b = (true and 1), (2 or 3), 4
local a, b = (false and 1), (2 or 3), 4
```

It's only by coincidence that you got the result you wanted in the true case. You could write something like this instead, which will work all the time:

```
local a, b
if false then
    a, b = 1, 2
else
    a, b = 3, 4
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local a, b = true and 1, 2 or 3, 4
```

is equivalent to

```
local a = 1 -- because true and 1 is 1
local b = 2 -- because 2 or 3 is 2
```

Further

```
local a, b = false and 1, 2 or 3, 4
```

is equivalent to

```
local a = false -- because false and 1 is false
local b = 2 -- because 2 or 3 is 2
```

There is no actual need to use multiple asignment here. So simply use

```
local a = condition and 1 or 3
local b = condition and 2 or 4
```

or

```
local a, b
if condition then
  a, b = 1, 2
else
  a, b = 3, 4
end
```

Also there is no point in using a constant as your condition value. It will always yield the same result so why not use that result right away.